# Shortest ES6 way to find a value of object by name in array of objects?

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

Hi I have a collection (array) "message.payload.headers" with this content:

[image]

What is the latest, shortest ES6 way to get a value of the **From** field (where name === "From") in typescript/javascript? without any looping of course? Thanks.

Comment: Without looping?... you're going to have to go through that array _somehow_...

Comment: You cannot do it without looping unless you have a lookup method. And arrays only have indexed access.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
message.payload.headers.find(header => header.name === 'From').value;
```

Comment: Damn, yes, simple arrow function

Comment: Don't access `.value` immediately. First check whether `find` has returned something - it might not have found anything satisfying the predicate.